# Ansible: conflicting action statements in tasks/main.yml file

Tags: python, ansible

Here is my directory structure:

```
/roles
    /apache
        /files
        /handlers
        /meta
        /tasks
        /templates
        /vars
ansible.cfg
hosts
playbook.yml
```

Here is my tasks/main.yml file contents:

```
---
- name: Add Apache2 repository
  apt_repository: repo='ppa:ondrej/apache2' state=present
  register: apacherepositoryinstalled

- name: Install Apache2
  apt: pkg=apache2 state=latest update_cache=true
  when: apacherepositoryinstalled|success
  register: apacheinstalled
  service: name=apache2 state=started

- name: Enable rewrite module
  apache2_module: state=present name=rewrite
  when: apacheinstalled|success
  register: rewritemoduleenabled

- name: Add production virtual host configuration
  template: src=production.conf.j2 dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/production.conf owner=root group=root

- name: Enable production virtual host configuration
  file: src=/etc/apache2/sites-available/production.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/production.conf

- name: Add staging virtual host configuration
  file: src=staging.conf.j2 dest=/etc/apache2/sites-available/staging.conf owner=root group=root

- name: Enable staging virtual host configuration
  file: src=/etc/apache2/sites-available/staging.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/staging.conf

- name: Reload Apache2 Service
  service: name=apache2 state=reloaded
```

Here is the following error message that is thrown by the Ansible script:

```
The error appears to have been in '/home/vagrant/ansible/roles/apache/tasks/main.yml': line 6, column 4, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- name: Install Apache2
  ^ here
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple actions specified. `service` has to a separate action. Change it to:

```
- name: Install Apache2
  apt: pkg=apache2 state=latest update_cache=true
  when: apacherepositoryinstalled|success
  register: apacheinstalled
- service: name=apache2 state=started
```

Comment: Thanks!  Can I specify "notify" as an individual task?  When I try to do - name: Reload Apache2 Service -notify: Restart Apache it tells me no action is specified.